# Managing the Playwright browser with Unittest

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest, playwright, playwright-python

I'm kinda new in coding and was asked to do a test for the company web login, they want me to implement the module unitestt and playwright test generator tool. This is what I have so far. I had to separate run from test_1 since unittest failed while reading the chromium line but now it only opens the browser so what can I do in order for it to run the whole test?

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
from locators import Locators_evou
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(channel ="chrome", headless=False,slow_mo=500)
        context = browser.new_context()

        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("http://localhost:3000/")

    def test_1(page):   
        page.click(Locators_evou.user_Log)
        page.fill(Locators_evou.user_Log, "Liliana")
        page.click(Locators_evou.password_log)
        page.fill(Locators_evou.password_log, "1234")
        page.check(Locators_evou.session_Log)
        page.click(Locators_evou.login_log)

        assert page.is_visible("¡Bienvenido!")
        
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run(playwright)

   
if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I'd imagine it fails because `Test` has no attribute `chromium`. You need `self` as the first argument for `run`, as well as `playwright`. See the [basic example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) from the docs.

Comment: Tried to add self in def run (self, playwright) but now I have this error
Test.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'playwright'

Comment: I'd recommend to use the official Pytest plugin for Playwright: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-runners and create functional tests (function tests vs. class based tests) instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this example in Python 3.10.12, which [skips the `with` context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73055442/6243352) and doesn't require pytest, as the official docs example currently uses:

```py
import unittest
from playwright.sync_api import expect, sync_playwright  # 1.37.0


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.p = sync_playwright().start()
        cls.browser = cls.p.chromium.launch()
        cls.context = cls.browser.new_context()
        cls.context.set_default_timeout(5_000)

    def setUp(self):
        self.page = Test.context.new_page()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.page.close()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.context.close()
        cls.browser.close()
        cls.p.stop()

    def test_example(self):
        "validate header on example.com"
        self.page.goto("https://www.example.com")
        expect(self.page.locator("h1")).to_have_text("Example Domain")

    def test_quotes_login(self):
        "login to quotes.toscrape"
        page = self.page
        page.goto("http://quotes.toscrape.com")
        page.get_by_text("login").click()
        page.type('input[name="username"]', "foo")
        page.type('input[name="password"]', "bar")
        page.get_by_role("button", name="Login").click()
        page.get_by_text("Logout").wait_for()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```